# Missing HTTP status in the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

I have a restful api built on top of a rails 3 app, i am raising a custom exception error whenever an entity is not found like below

```
@line = @current_account.lines.find(:first, :conditions =>{:title => line_title})
raise CustomExceptionError.new("Line not found for title: #{line_title} under your account",404) if @line.nil?
```

here is the look at the CustomExceptionError class

```
class CustomExceptionError < StandardError
  attr_accessor :message, :status
  def initialize(message,status=422)
   @message = message
   @status = status
  end
  def to_s
   "#{@message}"
  end
end
```

and here is the method that is used to handle the exception

```
def custom_error_renderer(exception = nil)
  if exception
     logger.info "Rendering 404: #{exception.message}"
  end
  error = {:error => {:message => exception ? exception.message : "Undefined error."}}
  render :json => error, :status => exception.status
```

end

But when i look at the server log

```
18:12:09 action_controller Completed   in 18ms
18:12:09 action_controller Rendering 404: Line not found for title: dater98 under your account
```

the status code is missing in the log

if i render directly instead of raising the CustomExceptionError

```
render :status => 404, :json => {:error => {:message=> "Line not found for title: #{line_title} under your account""}}
```

then it returns the status code.

```
Completed 404 Not Found in 84ms (Views: 75.7ms)
```

I have no idea what i am doing wrong here. any suggestions or guess???

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue on my machine. How are you getting logs to look like they do?

Comment: i'm tailing tail -f log/development.log

Comment: That doesn't look like the output of that to me. For one, there's no timestamps at the *beginning* of each line. I have this, for example: `Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)`

Comment: i am not using active record. I am using mongoid instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you render with a status, it will send the standard 404 response from your public/404.html file.

You could try deleting your public/404.html file.

Comment: First of all, its a json API req/res. So not html files gets rendered. Please read the question carefully. The correct status code is returned as expected. The only problem is that it doesn't get printed on the log.